# How to dynamically update Install button to Open on mobile site in case the app is installed?

Tags: android, ios, app-config, appxmanifest

I have an installation banner on my mobile site with a Install button which links to play store or app store depending on OS. However I want the button to change to open in case the user already has my app installed. I read and tried intent, but this would not dynamically change the button text. At least for the first attempt we have to provide both options and then store the response via cookies. Is my understanding correct or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you put your code of mobile site so that it would be easy here for people to understand it better. Also your current question is not interesting and people may find it boring so they will either ignore it or close it.

Comment: Try this : <a href="intent:#Intent;action=my_action;end">Link to my stuff</a>